# Tabs issue in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have tab for image thumbnail in my page using CSS and Javascript. When I loaded my page, it only showed tab but not the content in relative tab. Please find below code and help me.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }

        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to acheive , but I can say 
instead of
 tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
you can do like 
tablinks[i].classList.remove(" active");

Comment: This will definitely need some additional explanation. The function referenced above never even gets called, so it's hard to know where the disconnect is. Can you add a working sample of the code, or example?

Answer (score 1):

I basically saw two typos in your code...

Is it really ***eat*** or you just mistyped and should be evt?

```
function openCity(eat, cityName) {
```

and basically at this point causing the tablinks variable being unused and this can be breaking your code

```
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
```

So I correct it and you could you try again, as this code LGTM

```
<script>
  function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
      }

      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }
</script>
```

in case, if you don't need to support +IE8 you could replace this for by map method - http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5